# Can student hours transfer from Argentina to USA to take the PPL test?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, ppl, student-pilot

Can the 40+ hours done with a certified flight instructor in Argentina count as the required hours for the private pilots license here in the United States?

The timing of the final test isn't working out and needs to be done in the state if possible. If so, are there any specific documents other than the proof of hours flown and the certification proof of the flight instructor required?  From what I've read it seems like this can be done.  Just need to redo the medical and perhaps the classroom work.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the flight training, per 14 CFR § 61.41(a)(2):

> A person may credit flight training toward the requirements of a pilot certificate or rating issued under this part, if that person received the training from [...] A flight instructor who is authorized to give such training by the licensing authority of a foreign contracting State to the Convention on International Civil Aviation, and the flight training is given outside the United States.

Make sure that you are logging your time in accordance with FAA rules, and that your training meets all FAA requirements. Not every country has exactly the same requirements so you may still have things to do.

You'll need to pass the other requirements in the US. Namely, you'll need to get an FAA medical, pass the written test, and receive the required endorsements to take the practical test.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It seems the logbook will be in compliance with the info provided.  Do you know if it will be an issue that it is Spanish?

Comment: @MarciePyke I don't know of any regulatory requirement that it be in English. But of course your DPE needs to be able to read it. It would be a good idea to make a new logbook with the entries translated to English. Though you'll still need to bring your old logbook that has your CFI's signatures in them.

Comment: Thank you again!